# How to upload ContentVersion records using BulkAPI?

Tags: bulk-api

So I've been trying to follow the sample java app provided in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_code_walkthrough.htm) to write some Java code to upload ContentVersion records (files) into Salesforce using the Bulk API. It should be so maddeningly simple:
[image]
So I've been trying, but regardless of the approach I try, I end up getting this:

```
Failed with error: INVALID_FIELD:Failed to deserialize field at col 2. Due to, 
InvalidBatch : Invalid file reference: /Users/myuser/repos/BulkFileLoader/temp/Batch_1/samplefile.txt:VersionData --
```

I am creating a temp folder, moving my files into the folder and creating a request.txt file in the same folder, then using

```
batchInfo = bulkConnection.createBatchFromDir(myJob, null, tempFolder);
```

I have also tried to provide the whole thing as a stream using this method:

```
private BatchInfo createBatchFromFiles(JobInfo job, Path fileDir, Path newCsv)
            throws AsyncApiException, IOException
    {

        Map<String, InputStream> attachments = new HashMap<>();
        for (File f : fileDir.toFile().listFiles())
        {
            Path filePath = Paths.get(f.toURI());
            attachments.put(f.getAbsolutePath(), Files.newInputStream(filePath));
        }

        return bulkConnection.createBatchWithInputStreamAttachments(job, Files.newInputStream(newCsv), attachments);
    }
```

Both approaches give me exactly the same error.

Here's the request.txt file generated:

```
Title,Description,VersionData,PathOnClient
samplefile.txt,samplefile.txt,/Users/myuser/repos/BulkFileLoader/temp/Batch_1/samplefile.txt,/Users/myuser/repos/BulkFileLoader/temp/Batch_1/samplefile.txt
```

When I convert my request.txt file to request.csv and try uploading with the Data Loader, there are no issues - so apparently the Data Loader is doing some magic on the files, but looking through the Data Loader source code, I have not been able to figure out what.

Any help to get this simple example working would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently, writing out this question helped... a lot. After a bit more experimentation, the only thing that needed changing was the output in the request.txt file: the VersionData field needs just the filename prefixed with a # like this:

```
Title,Description,VersionData,PathOnClient
samplefile.txt,samplefile.txt,#samplefile.txt,/Users/myuser/repos/BulkFileLoader/temp/Batch_1/samplefile.txt
```

Either of the two approaches (using createBatchWithInputStreamAttachments or createBatchFromDir) works equally well.